# Which kind of Library should I use for Socket programming in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to know which library is good for a high speed TCP packet receiving mode without less CPU interruption(Stream(BinaryStream or StreamReader or Net.Socket).

Thanks

Comment: All libraries using Net will probably give same performance.  Adding a stream to TCP will have more overhead than using a socket by itself.  Best method in Net is to use ASYNC methods (not SYNC).  SYNC methods do not run reliabily in Windows no matter what library is used.

Comment: Are you writing a server, or a client? it matters

Comment: @jdweng oh, I'd massively disagree there; there's *huge* changes in this area in the last few years, *especially* when writing servers (the pieces for writing clients haven't landed yet, at least not in the Microsoft bits, but there are non-Microsoft APIs that add it), that give *very clear advantages* in some directions

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, I need to write a reliable client part not to miss any packet and doesn't take CPU time very much.

Comment: @MarcGravell : That is why I said Net. You are referring to non managed code which is not Net.

Comment: @jdweng no, I'm not referring to non managed code

Comment: @JohnJin "not to miss any packet" - that's the job of TCP, not you; if "missing packets" is even a discussion point, you should be using UDP

Comment: FWIW, I also disagree on the closing of this question - IMO it is pretty valid to ask about the current suitable approaches for achieving a given aim; however, I try hard not to vote on open/close decisions unless I'm *absolutely 100% certain* of a ruling, because my ♦ makes my votes too strong

Comment: @MarcGravell Help center still states "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow" This question is explicitly asking to recommend a library and nothing else, so it is beyond any doubt it is off topic. I don't mind if rules change, but for now they haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're writing a *server*, then: "pipelines", ideally hosted in Kestrel, and running on .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5+. The pipelines API is *designed from the ground up* to allow very efficient performance for large numbers of TCP connections, simply via the `UseConnectionHandler<T>` API (example [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/toys/KestrelRedisServer/Program.cs#L24)).

The pipelines API is very different to `Stream` and `Socket`; I have a multi-part blog series discussion it [here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html) (see also pt 2, 3 and 3.1).

There is not currently an official pipelines API for writing clients, but I have a 3rd-party implementation [on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/) that allows client usage.

Comment: Thank you very much and I really appreciate your help, what about the client mode?

Comment: @JohnJin like I said: there's no official pipelines client support yet, although the API is being actively discussed; Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial provides 3rd party (i.e. non-Microsoft) support for client-based pipelines